# Why in GWT an interface is instantiated?

Tags: java, gwt

Going through this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC it is mentioned that to set up a call back Object it is necessary to do the following:

```
// Set up the callback object.
AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    // TODO: Do something with errors.
  }

  public void onSuccess(StockPrice[] result) {
    updateTable(result);
  }
};
```

However I noticed AsyncCallback is an interface. As far as I knew interfaces could not be instantiated. How is this possible?

Comment: Anonymous implementation and spontaneous instantiation of an interface. That is due to Java, not GWT. You can do it to any Java interface and Eclipse would prompt you to implement the unimplemented methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of using an Anonymous Class to implement a callback in Java. This is equivalent to defining a class that implements that interface. To clarify, this:

```
new AsyncCallback() {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
public class MyCallback implements AsyncCallback {
    ...
}
```

In fact, if you wanted to, you *could* create your own `class` in a separate Java file, call it `MyCallback`, and then do this:

```
AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback = new MyCallback();
```

It's all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case of anonymous inner class implementation of that interface.

The demonstrated approach is very frequently used for implementing different listeners and callbacks. More on the topic can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).